# Difficulty Connecting to SQL Server with SQL Workbench

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-workbench-j

\I'm able to connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express(SSMSE) on the same machine as the database. I need to connect to it from another machine on the same network. My phase 1 is SQLWorkbench.

Here's the settings that work on SSMSE:

```
Server type: Database Engine
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
Server Name: ABC\123
```

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager it shows that `Shared Memory`, `TCP/IP`, and `Named Pipes` are all Enabled and the `TCP/IP` default port is 1433.

In SQL Workbench, I'm trying this for the URL:

> jdbc:sqlserver://ABC\123:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase;integratedSecurity=true;

I've tried with and without the databaseName and integratedSecurity. On each attempt, I'm getting this error:

> The TCP/IP connection to the host RMS, port 1433 has failed. Error:
>   "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that
>   an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port
>   are not blocked by a firewall.".

I should mention that I have successfully connected to other SQLServer databases using SQLWorkbench from this same machine. Also, ABC\123 is not the real server name but it is in that format.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to install SSMSE on the remote machine you would be using to make connections? You can actually use it to connect to remote SQL Server instances as well.

Comment: Did you try specifying it using the instanceName: jdbc:sqlserver://ABC;instanceName=123;integratedSecurity=true

Answer (score 0):

Probably a long-shot, but have you tried specifying `MultiSubnetFailover=True` in your connection properties?

Comment: I tried it. That changes my error to `Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.`